# Basic Number Function

Tags: python, function, combinations

Hey trying to speed this function up hoping for help. Im well aware this is sloppy :/

Anyway, it takes 3 inputs array length (the length of the next input), lst (the array which we will use to sum up and find a target), target (the number I'm trying to compute).

As mentioned it takes the list and then adds each 2 number combination of elements together until it finds the target variable then outputs just one if many exist. If none then print none. Thanks in advance

```
l = 43
input_array = range(43)
t = 30


def target_finder():
  l = input()
  input_array = input()
  t = input()

  l = int(l)
  input_array = input_array.split()

  arr = []
  for el in input_array:
    arr.append(int(el))

  t = int(t)

  x = []
  for el in arr:
    for num in range(l):
      x.append(tuple((el, arr[num], (el + arr[num]))))


  y = []
  for el in x:
    if el[2] == target:
      y.append(el[0])
      y.append(el[1])
  
  if len(y) <2:
    print('None')
  elif y[0] == y[1]:
    print('None')
  else:
    print(y[0], y[1])
```

output for above could be 10, 20

Comment: how many numbers should the output be? only 4? or can it be 3 or 2, etc..

Comment: Oh its limited to 2 numbers ill correct now sorry

Comment: You can't speed up a function containing a call to `input()`...

Comment: I believe its the way I am indexing the values and using lists that are slowing things down really

Comment: This is a famous problem called Two Sum (https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/). One way to solve it in `O(nlogn)` time (assuming the list is sorted) would be to loop over the list, update your target as `new_target = target - list[i]` and then binary search the list for the new target. Another way would be using two pointers (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/)

Comment: list comprehensions could get rid of the append calls as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319205826/http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/), and maybe make a really slight difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is my attempt at this problem. I loop through the elements, and check if the `element - target` is in the array, and if the `element - target != element`. Also, I moved to function arguments instead. I believe the time complexity is `O(n²)`

```py
def target_finder(input_array, target):
    matches = []
    for element in input_array[:-1]:
        if target - element in input_array and target - element != element:
            matches.append([element, target - element])

    if len(matches) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return matches


# Map is similar to iterating through and running the provided function on each element (in this case, int).
# print(target_finder(map(int, input("Target Array: ").split()), int(input("Target Number: "))))
print(target_finder(list(range(43)), 30))
```

Comment: thanks for this Im going to check out leetcode and hackerthon in future to work these headscracthing problems out in advance!

Comment: @DigitalMoniker my pleasure to help!